# Display file chooser dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How do I show a file chooser dialog on Mac OS X? The language is Objective C.

Comment: What programming language? Cocoa, carbon, etc.? What have you already tried?

Comment: @Delan Azabani, If he's asking this kind of question, he's probably talking Cocoa. Maybe Java. But you're right, this is far too ambiguous right now.

Comment: Sorry the language is objective C i have not tried anything yet because right now im developing an iPhoto library API as i am awaiting an reply on this question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you search is 'NSOpenPanel', here a example how to use:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]; // yes if more than one dir is allowed

NSInteger clicked = [panel runModal];

if (clicked == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
    for (NSURL *url in [panel URLs]) {
        // do something with the url here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it !. Only i had to comment out the click== part as NSFileHandlingPanelOkButton as not defined.

Comment: It could be because of the fact that i am developing Mac OS Lion that NSFileHandlingPanelOkButton was not found. It could have been deprecated ?.

Comment: but, i think it's a small misspelling, try: NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton, With OK and not Ok ;-)

Comment: It's been a while since I last programmed something using the Cocoa framework. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/index.html) you need the `@import AppKit;`...

Answer (score 5):

Those who are looking for **Swift version**

```
let panel                     = NSOpenPanel()
panel.canChooseDirectories    = false
panel.canChooseFiles          = true
panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
panel.allowedFileTypes        = ["txt"]
let clicked                   = panel.runModal()

if clicked == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
    print("URLS => \(panel.urls)")
}
```