# File manager class on OSX SDK?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display file chooser dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126594/display-file-chooser-dialog)

What is the name of the file manager GUI. Like when you save as on a program and a file manager comes up.
I'm talking about OSX 10.5 and upwards.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? The way that you access the file dialog is different depending on the language you're using. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry. Objective C is the language I am trying to accomplish it in. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126594/display-file-chooser-dialog

Comment: Adding to what nerdherd said, the counter part of the `NSOpenPanel` is, without surprise, `NSSavePanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when you save as on a program and a file manager comes up

You would use `NSSavePanel` for this.

If you simply want to open a document or choose a directory, then you would use `NSSavePanel's` subclass - `NSOpenPanel`.

Comment: @Vervious i was originally responding to "when you save as on a program and a file manager comes up". anyways, I have expanded the answer to include NSOpenPanel. thanks +1

Comment: thanks for the clarification - that's what I meant. I've already +1'd your answer :)