# How to add UI element for choosing a file to Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to select an input file and an output destination for my mac app

Currently I can use a text field and drag an item from finder into it to get the correct path.

But how do I have a button open finder from within the app and let me choose which file i want from here It will automatically get the path to file (choose file button)

Also I want to select an output folder in the same kind of way(choose destination button)

I dont need full instructions on how to do this just an idea of how to implement it? Im new to Mac App design and dont know much of the framework yet

Is there a way to do this ?  or do i have to configure a button pragmatically to achieve this

Any help appreciated  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display file chooser dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126594/display-file-chooser-dialog)

Comment: Yes and no I actually also just found NSPathControl.  Between the 2 I believe I can find what I am looking for.

Comment: How do I mark this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel`

Connect a button to an action in your view controller or window controller depending on how you have things set up.

Full docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsopenpanel_class/reference/reference.html) but it's simply a matter of getting the system panel.

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPannel];
```

Normally you will open modally via.

```
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:nil];
```

Same principal applies for the save panel.